# How do you make the height of an element the same as the width of an element which was calculated using clamp in CSS?

Tags: html, css, dimensions, clamp

I have an image element with a width of `clamp(100px, 160px, 27vw);`.

I want to make the height of the element the same as its width.

I tried using the attribute value of `auto` but it did not work.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Below is a snippet of the code:

```js
console.log(
  "The width of the element is",
  document.getElementById("img").offsetWidth +
  "px"
)

console.log(
  "The height of the element is",
  document.getElementById("img").offsetHeight +
  "px"
)
```

```css
img {
  width: clamp(100px, 160px, 27vw);
  height: auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/488px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png?20211218170823">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1`. I've modified your code to show the result. As of this writing (June/2022), support for `aspect-ratio` is [very good](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio).

```js
console.log(
  "The width of the element is",
  document.getElementById("img").offsetWidth +
  "px"
)

console.log(
  "The height of the element is",
  document.getElementById("img").offsetHeight +
  "px"
)
```

```css
img {
  width: clamp(100px, 160px, 27vw);
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<img id="img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fa/Apple_logo_black.svg/488px-Apple_logo_black.svg.png?20211218170823">
```